# Does open layers 3 and google maps have the same coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers-3

what to ask if open layers 3 and google maps have the same coordinates?

I want to use the service of openstreet map via open layers 3 to draw cities boundaries on google map.

Answer (score 4):

no, but you can transform them with:

```
ol.proj.transform([x,y], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

[Sorce](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#transform)

EPSG:4326 is the projection google maps uses and EPSG:3857 the one openlayers 3 uses.